# how to fix namespace missing in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, namespaces

I don't know what going on, I was setting my `mongodb` before. then I refresh my page and suddenly there was an error notification 
[asking for namespace missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMrHZ.png)

> Unable to find 'application\modules\home\models\User' in file: F:\aplikasi\laragon\www\yiiad\application/modules/home/models/User.php. Namespace missing?

I have already checked the codes I made before, and still don't know where my mistakes

This is my models user structure 
\application\modules\home\models\user

this models\user code

```
<?php 
namespace home\models; 

use Yii;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\db\Query;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{}
?>
```

My Alias

```
<?php
Yii::setAlias('@modules', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/application/modules');
```

My Path setting

```
'basePath' => '@modules/home',
'modules' => [
    'admin' => [
      'class' => 'admin\Module'
    ],
    'home' => [
      'class' => 'home\Module'
    ],
  ],
```

My modules

```
<?php
namespace home;
class Module extends \yii\base\Module{

public function init()
{
 parent::init();
    if (\Yii::$app instanceof \yii\console\Application) {
        $this->controllerNamespace = 'home\controllers';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Namespace `home` is incorrect. You should use `modules` alias in the namespace of the module

```
namespace modules\home;

class Module extends \yii\base\Module
{
}
```

and in config

```
'modules' => [
    'home' => [
      'class' => 'modules\home\Module'
    ],
],
```

Or you must set alias for `home` directory

```
'aliases' => [
    '@home' => 'path to home directory'
],
'modules' => [
    'home' => [
      'class' => 'home\Module'
    ],
  ],
```